# (com.facebook.sdk error 5.) in HelloFacebookSample demo

Tags: ios, facebook, sample

I install the latest 3.5.1 Facebook sdk, and run the HelloFacebookSample sample, get this error.

It might be network issue, and I change my network. The issue still appears.

```
> FBLoginView encountered an error=Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "
> The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0x9478eb0 
> {com.facebook.sdk:ErrorInnerErrorKey=Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "
> The certificate for this server is invalid. 
> You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “graph.facebook.com” which could put your confidential information at risk." UserInfo=0x9487810 

> {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://graph.facebook.com/me?sdk=ios&migration_bundle=fbsdk%3A20130409&format=json&access_token=CAAFDDRlIT2wBABhZCkQEYkQUT7ierG3pnw8O70QwZBJbda6m4KHDiJ4FUDsf8xo4Wy4MCjDrvx6DSxD1QTfWIS1EL7Uty7p8yiOxZBaF3LZBW9tmyA4nWUunLMDkvoaSkMy1AZCLLraZBCVGPYO7D19DQsc4Bu7QjPfVs6jiTZAeQZDZD, 
> NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, 
> NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://graph.facebook.com/me?sdk=ios&migration_bundle=fbsdk%3A20130409&format=json&access_token=CAAFDDRlIT2wBABhZCkQEYkQUT7ierG3pnw8O70QwZBJbda6m4KHDiJ4FUDsf8xo4Wy4MCjDrvx6DSxD1QTfWIS1EL7Uty7p8yiOxZBaF3LZBW9tmyA4nWUunLMDkvoaSkMy1AZCLLraZBCVGPYO7D19DQsc4Bu7QjPfVs6jiTZAeQZDZD, 
> NSLocalizedDescription=The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “graph.facebook.com” which could put your confidential information at risk., 
> NSUnderlyingError=0xa454f20 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “graph.facebook.com” which could put your confidential information at risk.", 
> NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=<SecTrustRef: 0x947acb0>}, 
> com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=200, 
> com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=<FBSession: 0x13c542e0, state: FBSessionStateOpen, loginHandler: 0x9478ef0, appID: 355198514515820, urlSchemeSuffix: , 
> tokenCachingStrategy:<FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy: 0x947dc90>,
> expirationDate: 2013-07-26 03:08:40 +0000,
>  refreshDate: 2013-05-27 05:55:46 +0000, 
> attemptedRefreshDate: 0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(
>)>}
```

What is the problem with the Facebook samples?

**What's more**

The same Facebook login code runs successfully last month. And from last week, all my previous projects did not login with Facebook.

Comment: Hi, Maxim, I didn't modify any code, it works. So it might be cause by Facebook.

Comment: Are you sure you're not using a proxy?